# Login page with either username or email using react

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a login page which should be logged in if we enter either username or email and password like that of Facebook where we are able to logged in either by email or phone number and password but have no idea how to do it. It would be good if someone would help me out. My code includes:

```
import React from 'react'

const Login = () => {
  return (
      <div>
          <form>
              <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="Email or UserName">
                      Email or username
                  </label>
                  <input 
                      type="email"
                      placeholder="email or username"
                      required
                      className= "Input" />
                  
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="Password">
                      Password
                  </label>
                  <input 
                      type="Password"
                      placeholder="Password"
                      required
                      className= "Input" />
                  
              </div>
              <button type = "submit">Log in</button>
          </form>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: Exactly what are you having a problem with?  It is unclear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Login = () => {
  const [UnameOrEmail, setUnameOrEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setpassword] = useState("");

  const user = {
    email: "test@test.com",
    username: "test123",
    password: "123456"
  };
  const handlesubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (UnameOrEmail === user.email || UnameOrEmail === user.username) {
      if (password === user.password) {
        console.log("User Loged In");
      } else {
        console.log("wrong password");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("please check you username or Email");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handlesubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="Email or UserName">Email or username</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="email or username"
            required
            value={UnameOrEmail}
            onChange={(e) => setUnameOrEmail(e.target.value)}
            className="Input"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="Password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="Password"
            placeholder="Password"
            required
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setpassword(e.target.value)}
            className="Input"
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Log in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Login;
```